# Evaluating summation involving combinations

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

> If $\sum_{r=m}^{n} {^r}C_m=^{n+1}C_{m+1}$, evaluate: $$\sum_{r=m}^n (n-r+1)\cdot^rC_m$$

**My attempt:**

I know we can split the brackets into three parts and easily evaluate summation of $n\cdot^rC_m$ and $^rC_m$ using the given condition. However, I do not know how to deal with the $(-1)\cdot r\cdot^rC_m$ that comes in the expansion.

I know about many summation methods (break $r$ into $(r+1)-1$ and others), and many identities that help solve such expressions, but they don't match here, and hence I am unable to proceed any further.

Can anyone please give some hints? (include the identity you're using using, if any)

Comment: The first identity can be found by considering counting binary strings of $n+1$ digits and $m+1$ 1s. The leftmost 1 can be in the first position in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways, the second position in $\binom{n−1}{m}$ ways etc, summing these gives total arrangements $\binom{n+1}{m+1}$. The second one is much the same as we may argue using the positions of the next-to-leftmost 1 of a binary string length $n+2$ with $m+2$ 1s. It may be in position 2 in $\binom{1}{1}\binom{n}{m}$ ways, in position 3 in $\binom{2}{1}\binom{n−1}{m}$ ways etc, sum these to give $\binom{n+2}{m+2}$.

Comment: @N.Shales could you please write that as an answer, and illustrate with an example or two? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Identity**

$$\bbox[#FFA,15px,border: solid black 1px]{\sum_{r=m}^{n}\binom{r}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}\qquad(1)}$$

**Example**

Count bit strings with $n+1=8$ digits and $m+1=3$ "1"s by counting mutually exclusive cases where the *first* "1" is in different positions.

We are counting arrangements of bit strings either side of the red "1" and multiplying in each case.

$$\color{red}{1}1100000\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{0}{0}\binom{7}{2}$$
$$0\color{red}{1}110000\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{2}$$
$$00\color{red}{1}11000\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{2}$$
$$000\color{red}{1}1100\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{3}{3}\binom{4}{2}$$
$$0000\color{red}{1}110\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{4}{4}\binom{3}{2}$$
$$00000\color{red}{1}11\quad\longrightarrow \text{arrangements}=\binom{5}{5}\binom{2}{2}$$

add up all these 6 cases to give

$$\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{7}{2}=35$$

but this must add up to the total arrangements

$$\binom{8}{3}=35$$

**Second identity**

$$\bbox[#FFA,15px,border: solid black 1px]{\sum_{r=m}^{n}\binom{n-r+1}{1}\binom{r}{m}=\binom{n+2}{m+2}\qquad(2)}$$

Note: $\binom{n-r+1}{1}=n-r+1$.

**Example**

Count bit strings with $n+2=8$ digits and $m+2=4$ "1"s by counting mutually exclusive cases where the *second* "1" is in different positions.

We are, again, counting arrangements of bit strings either side of the red "1" and muliplying in each case.

$$1\color{red}{1}110000\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{2}$$
$$10\color{red}{1}11000\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{2}$$
$$100\color{red}{1}1100\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
$$1000\color{red}{1}110\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}$$
$$10000\color{red}{1}11\quad\longrightarrow\, \text{arrangements}=\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{2}$$

add up all these 5 cases to give

$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{2}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}+\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{2}=70$$

but this must add up to the total arrangements

$$\binom{8}{4}=70$$

as required.

Answer (score 2):

Given the form of the question, the desired answer is probably not a combinatorial argument. Consider instead $$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{r=m}^n (n - r + 1) \binom{r}{m} & = & \left((n+1) \sum_{r=m}^n \binom{r}{m} \right) - \sum_{r=m}^n r \binom{r}{m} \\
& = & (n+1)\binom{n+1}{m+1}  - \sum_{r=m}^n r \binom{r}{m} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
by the given identity. Now we presumably want to get the right hand side into a suitable form. The obvious way is to try eliminating the $r$ inside the sum by turning it into a series of sums of binomial coefficients. I.e. (with all the intermediate steps) $$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{r=m}^n r \binom{r}{m} & = & \left(m \sum_{r=m}^n \binom{r}{m}\right) + \left(\sum_{r=m}^n (r-m) \binom{r}{m}\right) \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} + \left( \binom{m+1}{m} + 2\binom{m+2}{m} + \ldots + (n-m)\binom{n}{m} \right) \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} + \sum_{j=m+1}^n \binom{j}{m} + \ldots \sum_{j=n}^n \binom{j}{m} \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} + \sum_{i=m+1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \binom{j}{m} \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} + \sum_{i=m+1}^n \binom{i+1}{m+1} \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} + \sum_{k=m+2}^{n+1} \binom{k}{m+1} \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} - \binom{m+1}{m+1} + \sum_{k=m+1}^{n+1} \binom{k}{m+1} \\
& = & m \binom{n+1}{m+1} - 1 + \binom{n+2}{m+2}
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $k = i+1$ is a change of variables.

Thus just using the given identity (ok, and $\binom{m+1}{m+1} = 1$) we get $$\sum_{r=m}^n (n - r + 1) \binom{r}{m} = (n-m+1)\binom{n+1}{m+1} - \binom{n+2}{m+2} + 1$$ which can no doubt be simplified.